# Changing php image upload filename to a specific name

Tags: php, database, timestamp

I want to change the uploaded image filename to a certain name for example: 
`Original name:city.jpg -> D0000_04042018094730121.jpg` 
(D0000 is kodeDosen and the other is a microtime timestamp.)
Here is my php code:
`uploadDosen.php`

```
 <?php
  include 'connectdb.php';

  if (isset($_POST['upload_Btn'])) {
    $target = "uploaddosen/".basename($_FILES['gambar']['name']);
    $kodeDosen = $_POST['kodeDosen'];
    $namaJurnal = $_POST['namaJurnal'];
    $tipePublikasi = $_POST['tipePublikasi'];
    $status= $_POST['status'];
    $gambar = $_FILES['gambar']['name'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_publikasi (kodeDosen,gambar,namaJurnal,tipePublikasi,status) VALUES ('$kodeDosen','$gambar','$namaJurnal',
    '$tipePublikasi','$status')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'],$target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }

    header("location:uploadTest.php");
    }




   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of **$target** to your preferred filename.

You can try:

```
$extention = explode(".", $_FILES['gambar']['name']);
$extention = end($extention);
$target = $kodeDosen."_".str_replace(array(".", " "), "", microtime() ).".".$extention;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
$target = "uploaddosen/".basename($_FILES['gambar']['name']);
```

Put your desired name in

```
$ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['gambar']['name'])));
$target = "uploaddosen/MYNEWNAME." . $ext
```

$ext is taking the uploaded file name and getting the file extension.  Then adding it together with your new name.

Comment: What if i want to change the format to  : (kodeDosen variable)_microtime timestamp.image extention   ex:D0000_04041810213411.jpg

Comment: $target = "uploaddosen/" . $kodeDosen . '_'. microtime() .".".$ext;

Comment: tested it and it doesnt show the kodeDosen variable as there is nothing behind the underscore,but the the microtime stamp works

Comment: Are you sure the Post variable $_POST['kodeDosen'] is not empty?  If not then $target = "uploaddosen/" . $_POST['kodeDosen'] . "_". microtime() . "." . $ext; should work